# How to make an update on field depending on linked document field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to conditionally update a field in a document but I need to know the value of an other field in a linked document. I'm struggling to explain my problem so i will give you my code and try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I got a route to update my 'workstation' collection

```
router.post("/workstation/update/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  const previousWorkstation = req.body.previous;
  const updatedWorkstation = req.body.updated;

  const {errors, isValid} = validateWorkstation(updatedWorkstation);
  if(!isValid){
    return res.status(422).json(errors);
  }

  Workstation.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), updatedWorkstation, (err, workstation) => {
    if(err) return;
    NonConformity.updateMany({workstation: previousWorkstation.name, line: previousWorkstation.line}, {$set:{workstation: updatedWorkstation.name}}, (err) => {
      if(err) return;
      Rework.updateMany({workstation: previousWorkstation.name}, {$set:{workstation: updatedWorkstation.name}}, (err) => {
        if(err) return;
        res.send(200);
      })
    })
  })
});
```

My problem is I need to update rework depending on the line too, and not only the workstation name ! Here are my schemas

```
// WORKSTATION SCHEMA

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const WorkstationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
  line: {type:String, required: true}
})

const Workstation = mongoose.model('workstations', WorkstationSchema);

module.exports = Workstation;

// REWORK SCHEMA 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ReworkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  nonConformity_id: {type:String, required: true},
  operator: {type:String, required: true},
  fin: {type:String, required: true},
  workstation: {type:String, required: false},
  code: {type:String, required: true},
  declination: {type:String, required: true},
  description: {type:String, required: true},
  advice: {type:String, required: false},
  pps: {type: String, required: false},
  quantity: {type:Number, required: true},
  reworked: {type:Boolean, default: false, required: true},
  verified: {type:Boolean, default: false, required: true},
})

const Rework = mongoose.model('nonConformities.reworks', ReworkSchema);

module.exports = Rework;

// NON CONFORMITY 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const NonConformitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  number: {type: String, unique: true, required: true, dropDups: true},
  line: {type: String, required: true},
  product: {type: String, required: true},
  workstation: {type: String, required: true},
  msn: {type: String, required: true},
  date: {type: String, required: true},
  type: {type: String, required: true},
})

const NonConformity = mongoose.model('nonConformities', NonConformitySchema);

module.exports = NonConformity;
```

My question is : Is it possible to update my workstation name in the rework collection depending on the line name of the linked non conformity id in the rework schema ?

Sorry if my english is bad, i can try to reformulate if you don't understand my question.

Thanks in advance !